# Can't accept invitation after clicking "View in TestFlight" button from Email

Tags: ios, testflight

I've a game and uploaded it to TestFlight for testing in internal testers.Everyone is getting invitation Email but after clicking "**View in TestFlight**" button it's not loading and after few minutes it's showing a message like below:[image]

Though all others app's invitation is working well.

Comment: I guess you might need to wait, as it is server side issue. We also uploaded a new version yesterday at TestFlight, and we are experiencing similar kind of issue (TestFlight in mobile could not connect to iTune server).
Looks they are doing some major updates. Will try tomorrow again.

Comment: same for me. Gateway timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TestFlight service is having an issue, users are affected globally. Please check 
[Apple Developer System Status](https://developer.apple.com/system-status/)